# Bash , Find modified files for the last x days

Tags: linux, bash, directory

Is there a way to find all files that have been modified the last x days from a specific directory?
I have done this

`find /home/user -iname "*.txt" -mtime -$x -print`
but it shows the files from user not from the directory.

the content of the directory is:

```
total 8
-rw------- 1 danae danae    0 Jun 21 22:08 a
dr-x------ 2 danae danae 4096 Jun 30 10:56 d
-rw------- 1 danae danae    0 Jun 30 10:56 file
-rw-rw---- 1 danae danae    8 Jun 29 13:03 file2
-rw-rw---- 1 danae danae    0 Jun 21 22:06 file3
-rwxrwx--x 1 danae danae    0 Jun 21 22:06 file4
-r-------- 1 danae danae    0 Jun 21 22:07 file5
-rw-rw-r-- 1 danae danae    0 Jun 21 22:07 file6
```

Comment: What is the directory you want to look in?

Comment: the user inputs it @Zachary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your current command

```
find /home/user -iname "*.txt" -mtime -$x -print
```

Is "/home/user" which is telling find to always look in that directory.

This should be replaced with the directory you want to look in. Or if you are doing this within a bash script first `cd` to the directory and then use

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -mtime -$x -print
```

Comment: I tried it and it does get into the directory , but it gives me 0 files, although i have modified them

Comment: What is the content of the directory, run the command `ls -l`  and include the output in your question.

Comment: I uploaded the content

Comment: None of those files match your filter "*.txt" means only show files that end with .txt

Comment: do you know what i have to change in order to correct it?

Comment: assuming your want to show all files edited in that specific time remove the -iname filter
`find . -mtime -$x -print`

Answer (score -1):

Use . to indicate the current directory:

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -mtime -$x -print
```